# jQuery select all elements that are visible or have display: none

Tags: jquery

I'm setting display: none on some elements for mobile, but I still want to select them using jQuery.

I know there's this

```
$(.connectedSortable[style*="display: none"])
```

But I'd also like to select the visible elements with class connectedSortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select visible elements, you can use the following code snippet.

```
$(".connectedSortable:visible")
```

To select hidden elements, you can use the following code snippet.

```
$(".connectedSortable:hidden")
```

**EDIT:** (As per comment)

To select hidden and visible elements for multi class selectors.

*Syntax:*

```
$(".className1, .className2").not(":visible"); // To get hidden elements

$(".className1, .className2").not(":hidden"); // To get visible elements
```

Comment: I think what I needed was a multiclass selector (no easy google for this solution). Hope this helps someone!